# Jquery css z-index Math.random() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create simple polaroid-style gallery. I'm doing okay with random positioning and css-transition rotation, but when it comes to randoming z-index, i'm failing (i need it, because it's ugly when the same image lies above all other whenever you shuffling)

http://jsfiddle.net/PWHAL/1/ - here is jsfiddle, i commented lines with z-index random

Best case for testing is grouping button

IPORTANT NOTE: code runnable only on webkit, because i was testing css transition properties only for this engine
Code example:

```
var realWidth = $(document).width();
var realHeight = $(document).height();
$("#polaroidButton").click(function() { 
    $(".hiddenh1").hide();
    $(".picCont").each(function() {
        $(this).css({
            '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(' +Math.random()*360 +'deg)', 
            "left" : Math.random()*(realWidth-400),
            'top' : Math.random()*(realHeight-440),
            'z-index' : Math.random()*100 + 51
        });
    });
});
```

This stuff even supposed to work?

Comment: What is broken about the z-index? It seems ok to me

Comment: Click 10 more times "Groups pls" button, and if you get div's 1/2 above 3, 4/5 above 6 or 7/8 above 9, then there is a problem with my browser =/

Comment: Add the parseInt like Arjun said to all your z-inde instances and it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to make sure that the random number is a whole integer?

```
'z-index' : parseInt(Math.random()*100, 10) + 51
```

Comment: Just checked on localpc, nothing new :(

Comment: I'm sorry man, missed line on testing. With parseInt all works perfectly, thank you!